# Didn't understand the following comment (in bold) on Bruce Eckel's "Thinking in C++" on its page 624 Vol. 1

Tags: c++, constructor, initializer-list

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
ofstream out("order.out");

#define CLASS(ID) class ID { \
public: \
  ID(int) { out << #ID " constructor\n"; } \
  ~ID() { out << #ID " destructor\n"; } \
};

CLASS(Base1);
CLASS(Member1);
CLASS(Member2);
CLASS(Member3);
CLASS(Member4);

class Derived1 : public Base1 {
  Member1 m1;
  Member2 m2;
public:
  Derived1(int) : m2(1), m1(2), Base1(3) {
    out << "Derived1 constructor\n";
  }
  ~Derived1() {
    out << "Derived1 destructor\n";
  }
};

class Derived2 : public Derived1 {
  Member3 m3;
  Member4 m4;
public:
  Derived2() : m3(1), Derived1(2), m4(3) {
    out << "Derived2 constructor\n";
  }
  ~Derived2() {
    out << "Derived2 destructor\n";
  }
};

int main() {
  Derived2 d2;
}
```

"Note that the
constructors are not default constructors; they each have an int
argument. The argument itself has no identifier; **its only reason for
existence is to force you to explicitly call the constructors in the
initializer list**"

Comment: -1: The question is poorly stated. It isn't clear whether the text passage is from the book (I assume it is) or from you. You shouldn't just quote a passage from a book and some code and call it a question.

Comment: Why the existance of an int argument in a constructor would force a call with an initializer list ?

Comment: Please tell me this code didn't come directly from a book! `ID`'s destructor should be `virtual` and the initialiser lists should be ordered (such as `: Base1(3), m1(2), m2(1)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the classes have a user-defined constructor and that user-defined
constructor is not the default constructor, there is no default
constructor available in those classes.

This makes it necessary to explicitly mention one of the available
constructors in the member initializer list of a derived class.

```
class Derived : public Base {
  Derived() {} // fails to compile, no constructor Base::Base() available
  Derived() : Base(3) {} // works
};
```

So much for what the code does and how it achieves it. I have no idea
why you should ever need something like that, but you never know.

Comment: It's probably just as an example of how you have to write a constructor when the base class has no default constructor

Comment: @SethCarnegie That would be a horrible way of teaching something.

Comment: but it would be even worse if it wasn't for teaching something

Answer (score 0):

What it means that the argument has no identifier - no name - and thus it is not used anywhere in the constructor.

But, when you make an object that belongs to the derived class, it's constructor calls the constructor of the parent class. Also, when you have an object member, you have to initialize it in your constructor.

If the parent class had a default (no-arguments) constructor, you would not have to call it at all - it would have been done automatically. Also, if you do not initialize the object member, it will be done automatically via the default constructor.

Since none of your classes actually have a default constructor, you have to **explicitly** call the parent class constructor, and also initialize members via their only existing constructor with one argument.

Using the unnamed argument in all the classes does just that - forces you to explicitly call their constructors, instead of just relying on the default constructor being called.

Answer (score 0):

Providing a constructor that takes an argument prevents the compiler from synthesising a default constructor. This forces the user of the `ID` class to provide an `int`, which is discarded, when creating an instance of this class. I can see no practical application of this approach.

To simplify this demonstration code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct ID
{
    ID(int)
    {
        std::cout << "ID  constructor" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    ID this_will_compile(0);
    ID this_will_not_compile;
}
```

While the first creation of an instance of `ID` will succeed, the second attempt will fail. You compiler will tell you something like:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘ID::ID()’

The same is true for deriving from such a class:

This will work...

```
struct DerivedWorking: public ID
{
    DerivedWorking()
        :ID(0)
    {
    }
};
```

Whereas this will not, because it doesn't provide an `int` to `ID`'s constructor...

```
struct DerivedBroken: public ID
{
    DerivedBroken()
    {
    }
};
```